# Recursion relations of Associated Legendre Polynomials with Schmidt Semi-normalization

Tags: geomagnetism

Can someone please provides me with the recursion relations of Associated Legendre Polynomials when using Schmidt quasi-normalization? I need that in the context of Geomagnetism to obtain the Spherical Harmonics coefficients g and h.

Comment: The answers here might help with this also, for future browsers: https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/22368/14123

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FYI, the usual reference relied on for the equations used in geomagnetism is:

- Langel, R. A. "Chapter four: Main field." Geomagnetism, edited by JA Jacobs (1987).

If it wasn't for lockdown I'd have copied from the book locked in my office to make sure I got it right...but until someone corrects me...

The Schmidt quasi/semi-normalisations for the associated Legendre polynomials are given by these recursions, in the form you'd actually use for calculations typically:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Note that if you use Schmidt normalisation of Legendre polynomials from a given software language to do calculations, you *do not* want to include the Condon-Shortley phase factor of [image]. So check if it is included in the Legendre polynomial and/or normalisation formula.

Edit: Some links to open source geomagnetism compatible software for calculating Schmidt normalised associated Legendre polynomials.

Python: [ChaosMagPy](https://github.com/ancklo/ChaosMagPy/blob/72c22e67dc844a71dcb678a1e81bdcde9f0c9627/chaosmagpy/model_utils.py#L665)

Python/Fortran-95: [SHTools](https://github.com/SHTOOLS/SHTOOLS/blob/master/pyshtools/legendre/legendre_functions.py)

Comment: That exactly what I was looking for, except I couldn't find the mentioned reference anywhere on the web, so thanks for the hint. However, I really need a confirmation about the formula correctness including the derivatives too.

Comment: I don't think there is a digital version of Langel (1987) anywhere online, but I just found I could view enough of the following reference through Google Books to confirm the equations:
Wertz, J. R. "Spacecraft Attitude Determination and Control", (1978).
Use the "Search inside" option and search for "Appendix H", you can see the first few pages about Schmidt normalisation.

Comment: That was useful, thanks again! So, the factors S are used with Gauss functions to obtain Schmidt functions, where: P_Schmidt = S * P_Gauss. But, it's still a long way to go with. I would love to compute directly the P_Schmidt functions since we know that there's recursion relations for them out there.

Comment: Are you actually after the final recursive formula for the Schmidt P_n^m(cos(theta)) functions themselves, or are you ultimately trying to write code to calculate these values for geomag problems? I can add links to open source code in a few languages much more easily than I can work back and type up the formula working from those codes right now!

Comment: Exactly I'm trying to implement a code to calculate those values, any open source code is welcomed! but I can't just take the code without the formula since I need to document that.

Comment: I understand, I've added links to the two clearest and most accessible examples of code.  There also a C library, Fortran-77, Python/C, and Matlab code I can dig out if those would be better.

Comment: To work out the final recursion formula, you need to take the normalisation formula above, combine them with the unnormalised Legendre recursion formula, and cancel them down. There's a special case for the first couple of terms, and for geomag use, the d.P_n^m(cos(theta))/d.theta terms needed are actually equivalent to values of P_m^{n+1}(cos(theta)).

Comment: @WJB you might be able to shed some light on this; I've asked [How can I verify my reconstructed gravity field of Ceres from spherical harmonics?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/27779/12102) and there might be some helpful information at [How are the coefficients in the EGM96 model normalized?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/12617/12102) but I can't tell. I want to generate the gravitational potential for Ceres so I can propagate orbits around it (e.g. Dawn spacecraft) but I don't know how to get it from those coefficients. I want to do it myself rather than use a library.